# Collection per content type

Tags: entities, database

I just started experimenting with the mongodb module and its fields storage module on a clean drupal install and it all seems to work fine.
But what I noticed is that the content of the 2 custom content types is stored in the same collections (fields_current.node and fields_revision.node).

Wouldn't it make sense to have a separate collection for each content type? As queries are often per content type, it should reduce the scope of your query?
Is there a possibility to do that with the current version of the module, or am I just not getting it?

Comment: Certainly looks like that's the default, but it does seem strange. A single collection wouldn't scale as well as separate ones when you start adding a lot of types/fields. I'm sure they had a reason, would love to know what it is

Answer (score 2):

My question got answered on drupal.org:

> Posted by marcingy on August 16, 2013 at 7:03pm:
>
> > This is mirroring how core storage works. fields_current.node contains the data for the current revision. There is a collection per entity type which is the smallest division in core in terms of storage.

I guess I will have to build in the flexibility myself :-)